# SIGQUIT breaks the pipe

Tags: command-line, networking, pipe, signal

Linux ping utility can produce some statistics on receiving `SIGQUIT` without terminating. It looks like this:

```
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=45 time=37.8 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=45 time=36.3 ms
2/2 packets, 0% loss, min/avg/ewma/max = 36.399/37.126/37.672/37.854 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=3 ttl=45 time=36.2 ms
^C
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2003ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 36.294/36.849/37.854/0.711 ms
```

As you can see I sent `SIGQUIT` right after second request by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd> and immediately got statistics.

But things are different when I'm trying to use ping with pipe. The command:

```
ping -O 8.8.8.8 | while read pong; do echo "$(date): $pong"; done
```

This time sending `SIGQUIT` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd>) breaks the pipe:

```
Tue Jul 30 18:15:20 EEST 2019: PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
Tue Jul 30 18:15:20 EEST 2019: 64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=45 time=71.1 ms
Tue Jul 30 18:15:21 EEST 2019: 64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=45 time=51.4 ms
Tue Jul 30 18:15:22 EEST 2019: 64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=3 ttl=45 time=54.5 ms
Tue Jul 30 18:15:23 EEST 2019: 64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=4 ttl=45 time=56.5 ms
Tue Jul 30 18:15:24 EEST 2019: 64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=5 ttl=45 time=56.5 ms
Tue Jul 30 18:15:25 EEST 2019: 64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=6 ttl=45 time=60.1 ms
6/6 packets, 0% loss, min/avg/ewma/max = 51.421/58.394/63.927/71.104 ms
Quit (core dumped)
```

Could someone please tell what is the cause of this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default behavior while sending a `SIGQUIT` is to make a process to:

1. Create a core dump
2. Terminate

However `SIGQUIT` can be handled and ignored, Which `ping` is doing this! thus `SIGQUIT` causes `ping` to print a short statistics without termination of the actual process.

Using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd> you are sending `SIGQUIT` to both side of your commands. The second part is not handling the signal and behaves as expected! creates a coredump then gets terminated and you end up with a broken pipe.

So, you should handle the signal yourself:

```
ping 1.1.1.1 | (oq() { echo 'wait'; }; trap oq QUIT; while read i; do echo $i; done)
```

Comment: I was about to post the same :) Do you know why the subshell (handling the while loop) crashes, though? Sounds like perhaps a bug in bash to me.

Comment: @Ravexina Thanks a lot, your answer is perfect.

Comment: @egmont What do you mean by crash?

Comment: @Victor You are welcome ;)

Comment: @dessert, moreover, you can use `trap` without function - `trap '' SIGQUIT`. The resulting command in my case would be `ping -O 8.8.8.8 | (trap '' SIGQUIT; while read pong; do echo "$(date): $pong"; done)`

Comment: @Ravexina I stand corrected here; for some reason I never realized that the default action for QUIT was to dump a core, and missed this in your post too. I thought the core was dumped due to a crash.